# Trying to dockerize Django app receive error "ERROR [3/6] RUN apk update"

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I'm completely new to Dockers, I'm trying to dockerize a Django application using:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.15

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN  apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

But when I run `docker build -t sometag .` I receive the following error:

```
 ERROR [3/6] RUN  apk update  && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev  && pip install --upgrade pip                                                                               10.5s
------
 > [3/6] RUN  apk update        && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev        && pip install --upgrade pip:
#6 0.396 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 5.402 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 5.402 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main: temporary error (try again later)
#6 5.402 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main: No such file or directory
#6 10.41 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community: temporary error (try again later)
#6 10.41 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community: No such file or directory
#6 10.41 2 errors; 36 distinct packages available
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update  && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev        && pip install --upgrade pip]: exit code: 2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it obvious is failing at your bash commands.

Be careful with indentation, it is very important in bash commands.

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip
```

If not that, than one of your libs.

Comment: Thank you, as you mentioned it was an indentation problem, now is working!